# Find the approximate value of π

Tags: approximation

We re given a ruler, a compass and square sheets of side length $a$. Using these we need to find the approximate value of π.

I tried to arrange the sheets similar to a graph paper. Then we can draw a circle of know (large) radius and approximately calculate the number of squares overlapping. We can fold the sheet for better approximation.

I want to know your views on this and please share other ways as well.

Comment: [Link](http://www.askamathematician.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/tumblr_lbxrvcK4pk1qbylvso1_400.png) Sorry, I couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.

As long as you can divide your square into many small squares you can get a good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a toothpick and graph paper. Draw parallel lines on the graph paper that are spaced a distance of 1 1/5 the length of the toothpick. Then put the graph paper on the floor and toss the toothpick onto it from several paces away. Do this a bunch of times keeping track of how many times the toothpick lands across a line (or either of the two edges of the paper parallel to the lines). Divide the total number of tosses by the number of times the toothpick lands on a line and then multiply the result by 5/3.